# Python not recognizing variable from import

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import, nameerror

I'm creating a small test game and I want to import a function from script2 into script1. Script2 is importing a player class from script3. Everything imports just fine, but when I try and reference the player class in script1, it gives me an error and says "NameError: name 'player' is not defined"

script1

```
import script2
import script3

createPerson()
print(player.name)
```

script2

```
import script3

def createPerson():
    global player
    
    new_name = input("What's their name? ")
    new_gender = input("What's their gender? ")
    new_age = int(input("What's their age? "))


    player = Person(new_name, new_age, new_gender)
```

script3

```
class Person:
    number_of_people = 0
    list_of_people = {}

    def __init__(self, name, age, gender, job="Unemployed"):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.job = job
        self.gender = gender
```

I can't figure this problem out. I'm new to python, so I need as much help as I can get

Answer (score 0):

script 1

```
from script2 import createPerson

player = createPerson()
```

script 2: defining "person" inside the function doesn't make it available outside it. Better you define a function that returns the created person and call it from script 1.

```
from script3 import Person


def createPerson():

    new_name = input("What's their name? ")
    new_gender = input("What's their gender? ")
    new_age = int(input("What's their age? "))

    person = Person(new_name, new_age, new_gender)

    return person
```

script 3: nothing changed